# How can I take the attribute value from pageContext to the scriptlet code inside my JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have the below piece of scriptlet code in my JSP.

```
<%   
      String instockMessage = pageContext.getAttribute("instockMessage");
      if ((instockMessage != null) && (instockMessage.trim().length() != 0)) {
            instockMessage = instockMessage.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").trim();
            pageContext.setAttribute("instockMessage", instockMessage);

      }
%>
```

But, I am getting an error saying that “: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String” on compilation.

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the pageContext.getAttribute() returns an Object. You have to Cast the Object to String to fix this issue:

```
String instockMessage = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("instockMessage");
```

OR

```
String instockMessage = pageContext.getAttribute("instockMessage").toString();
```

That is after modification your final code should look like this:

```
<%  
    String instockMessage = pageContext.getAttribute("instockMessage").toString();
    if ((instockMessage != null) && (instockMessage.trim().length() != 0)) {
        instockMessage = instockMessage.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").trim();
        pageContext.setAttribute("instockMessage", instockMessage);
    }
%>
```

OR

```
<%  
    String instockMessage = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("instockMessage");
    if ((instockMessage != null) && (instockMessage.trim().length() != 0)) {
        instockMessage = instockMessage.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").trim();
        pageContext.setAttribute("instockMessage", instockMessage);
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting into string:

```
String instockMessage = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("instockMessage");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you everything you need to know. The attributes from the page context are `Objects`, you need to downcast to a `String`. Do a

```
String instockMessage = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("instockMessage");
```

But for the sake of everything that is lovely in this world, avoid using scriplets and look into `JSTL`.